# document.write sometimes works, sometimes doesn't

Tags: if-statement, innerhtml, document.write

What am I doing wrong here? The last bit (kkk or mmm) doesn't work. How should I modify my code?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="#E6E6FA">
        <input type="text" id="userInput"></input>
        <button onclick="test()">Submit</button>
        <p id="Demo"></p>
        <p id="Beg"></p>
        <p id="Fin"></p>
        <script>
            function test()
            {
                var nam= document.getElementById("userInput").value;
                var l = nam.length;
                var sta = nam.slice(0,1);
                var las = nam.slice(-1);
                document.getElementById("Demo").innerHTML = document.write("Your secret code: " + l + sta + las);
                var one = nam.slice(-1)
                if (one == "a") {
                   document.write(nam.slice(0,-1) + "bbb");
                } else {
                   document.write(nam + "ccc"); 
                }         
                document.getElementById("Beg").innerHTML = document.write(". Your public code: ");
//This doesn't work:
                if (one == "l") {
                   document.write(nam.slice(0,-1) + "kkk");

                } else {
                   document.write(nam + "mmm"); 
                }


            }
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I've read similar questions but I'm still not sure what to do so I would really appreciate your help!

edit: The string ". Your public code: " is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is here:

```
document.getElementById("Beg").innerHTML = document.write(". Your public code: ");
```

document.write does not return a value. You should use istead

```
document.getElementById("Beg").innerHTML = ". Your public code: ";
```

Hope that helps.